# Reference request: the Brahma-Sûtra-Bhâshya of Śaṅkara

Tags: metaphysics, reference-request, ontology, eastern-philosophy, hinduism

The Brahma-Sûtra-Bhâshya of Śaṅkara is the commentary by Śaṅkara of the Brahma-Sûtra.
[Śaṅkara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adi_Shankara) was one of the greatest Hindu philosopher.
The [Brahma-Sûtra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahma_Sutra) is one the greatest text on **ontology** of the Vedānta school of Hindu philosophy.

The original text is in Sanskrit, but there exists many translations in English by :
 - Swami Sivananda
 - Swami Gambhirananda
 - Swami Vireswarananda
...

My mother tongue is French and I would like to find a French translation of the full text.
 Unfortunately, I have never found one.

- Is there one (published or not)?
- Else, how explain that such a fundamental text does not have a (full) French translation?
- Is there any translation work in progress?

**Remark** : A famous book seller on the Internet proposes a French edition [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8186569022), unfortunately it's not in French but in Spanish (see the back cover).

Comment: All the "Swami *ananda" names appear to be that of monks of the Ramakrishna Mission. (That's not always the case, but given a string of such names, that's what I'm betting on.) I guess you are in France. I think your best option is to visit/telephone the biggest Ramakrishna Mission in France. Indian publishers are not known to have an up-to-date catalog online.

Comment: Also, the book that you have linked to is Brahmasutra by Badarayana, not Sankara's commentary.

Comment: @prash thank you for your comments. You're right, Swami Gambhirananda and Swami Vireswarananda are from Ramakrishna Mission, but not Swami Sivananda. I have contacted this mission in France and they have not a French translation of the Brahma-Sûtra-Bhâshya of Śaṅkara.

Comment: @prash : Bādarāyaṇa is another name of Vyāsa, the author of the Brahma-Sûtra. In fact, I don't know if this spanish edition contains the Bhâshya (commentaries) of Śaṅkara.

Comment: Sorry about going off-topic, but how do you type those macrons and over-dots? I can manage carets such as û on my keyboard, but not macrons and the dots.

Comment: @prash : I did a copy-paste.

Answer (score 3):

I would assume that the [Bibliothèque nationale de France](http://www.bnf.fr/fr/acc/x.accueil.html) would hold a copy of such an edition, if it were to exist-- but a search of their catalogues shows nothing of the sort.

It's pretty difficult to prove a negative, but I'd doubt that there is such a translation.

> Else, how explain that such a fundamental text does not have a (full) French translation?

I suggest that you'll find that translations of Indian philosophy into European languages are spotty at best, and that this is not an exceptional case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also think that such a text is very hard to translate for western people. Indeed, the only English translations I know are of Hindu Swamis. These Swamis speaks English because India was a British colony, but a part of India was also a French colony (as Pondicherry), so perhaps there is a (unpublished) French translation of the Brahma-Sûtra-Bhâshya by a Swami living close to Pondicherry.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux: I think it's very unlikely that the Aurobindo/Pondicherry missionaries would be interested in translating Sankara's works. As far as I can tell, Aurobindo viewed his philosophy as an *improvement* on Advaita (non-dualisic) philosophy.

Comment: @prash : yes you're probably right, but maybe there are others āshrams at Pondicherry or around, and perhaps some French-speaking Swamis had translated the Brahma-Sûtra-Bhâshya of Śaṅkara (without publishing their works).